# The hotkey from the Entry module returns the previous values

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, tkinter-entry

What's wrong with this code? I'm just trying to get to know Python and CTkinter. I want to periodically update the data in Entry widgets and use them by pressing a hotkey. But if you use the code in this form, then after changing the data in the Entry on launching the hotkey, it will first give the original version, and then the updated one. WHERE DOES IT GET THE FIRST VALUE IF WE HAVE ALREADY UPDATED IT?

Code:

```
import customtkinter
import keyboard as kb
import time



def shut_number():
    date2 = date1.get()
    time2 = time1.get()
    shut = shutnumber.get()
    
    print ("New Value")
    print (date2,time2,shut)
    
    
    def vstavit():
        print("Hotkey print")
        print(date2,time2,shut)
        time.sleep(.5)
        kb.send("Tab")
        kb.write(date2)
        time.sleep(.5)
        kb.send("Tab")
        kb.write(time2)
        time.sleep(.5)
        kb.send("Tab")
        kb.send("Tab")
        kb.write(shut)
        

    kb.add_hotkey("Shift+1", vstavit)

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.title("my app")
app.geometry("800x150")
date1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, placeholder_text="Date")
date1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
time1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, placeholder_text="Time")
time1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=20)
shutnumber = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, placeholder_text="Shut")
shutnumber.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=20)
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="Save", command=shut_number)
button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ew", columnspan=4)
app.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

app.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
New Value
1 2 3
Hotkey print
1 2 3
New Value
11 22 33
Hotkey print
1 2 3
Hotkey print
11 22 33
New Value
111 222 333
Hotkey print
1 2 3
Hotkey print
11 22 33
Hotkey print
111 222 333
```

I want the hotkey to output the current Entry values once. Without this extra previous value

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMrXl.png)
Implemented via AHK - it turned out even better than expected

```
Gui, Add, Text,, Выберите дату
Gui, Add, DateTime, vMyDateTime,
Gui, Add, Text,, Выберите время
Gui, Add, Text,x12 y75, ЧЧ
Gui, Add, Text,x100 y75, :  ММ
Gui, Add, DropDownList,w50 x35 y70 vHour, 00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23
Gui, Add, DropDownList,w50 x130 y70 vMinute, 00|30|
Gui, Add, Text,x12 y95, Введите шут
Gui, Add, Edit, vShut
Gui, add, button, Default, Обновить
Gui, show, w300 h300, Настройка отложек 2.0
Gui, Add, Text,, Запуск сприпта после обновления данных по F1
Gui, Add, Text,x100 y230, Текущее значение:
return

ButtonОбновить:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
GGGG := SubStr(MyDateTime, 1 , 4)
MM := SubStr(MyDateTime, 5 , 2)
DD := SubStr(MyDateTime, 7 , 2)
Date = %DD%.%MM%.%GGGG%
Time = %Hour%:%Minute%
Gui, Font, bold
Gui, Add, Text,x30 y250, Дата %Date%   Время %Time%   Шут %Shut%
Return
GuiClose:
ExitApp



F1::
send {tab}
sleep 100
Send %Date%
sleep 100
send {tab}
sleep 100
send %Time%
send {tab}
sleep 100
send {tab}
sleep 100
send %Shut%
return
```

Comment: But I would still like to get a similar result in python